# Terms in Apache Kafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I read the [Apache Kafka documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart) and a couple of more articles to get a start on what Kafka is and how it can be used in my application. However, I am highly confused at this point.

I am unable to understand the difference between partition and brokers.

Kafka provides a replication factor for reliability. Are those replicated data 
present on the same machine?

Difference between a {High level, Low level} + {Producer, Consumer}

If Kafka doesn't store the consumer position, what are the best methods of storing it? Do people use databases or they may store it as local information to the client.

Is is a good idea to build a pub-sub system with Kafka and NodeJS (to provide rest API for the data)?

Can anyone guide me in this direction? Please comment if you want me to add any other relevant information that helps to better provide solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a good chance to brush up on my Kafka knowledge, so I'm sorry if this got a bit long.

Most answers here are derived from the very documentation you linked, or by googling the relevant documentation.

Since you indicated wanting to work with Node.js, [I will include some references to the arguably best (to my knowledge) Kafka 0.9.0 client **no-kafka**](https://github.com/oleksiyk/kafka), and discuss it in the last section too.

**Question 1**

> I am unable to understand the difference between partition and brokers

- Brokers:

  A broker is a server running a kafka instance, as is stated by the introduction:

  > > [Kafka is run as a cluster comprised of one or more servers each of which is called a broker.](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#introduction)
- Partitions:

  You publish and consume messages to/from a topic. A topic can be partitioned, and, if you are running a cluster with >1 brokers, partitions will be distributed on the brokers (kafka servers).

  > > [Each partition is an ordered, immutable sequence of messages that is continually appended to...](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_topics)

  This enables you to balance the load of high throughput topics. You can consume from one, many or all partitions as you wish. Which message goes to which partition is determined by your chosen partitioning strategy (e.g. hashing a key, setting partition while publishing etc.).

**Question 2**

> Kafka provides a replication factor for reliability. Are those replicated data present on the same machine?

If you mean replicated on the same machine, then no, that would be dubious at best as it couldn't withstand a simple server crash. The replication factor determines how many brokers (servers) each partition of the topic will be replicated on. So --replication-factor 3 would mean each partition is on 3 brokers, with one of them as the leader (accepting reads/writes) and the remaining two replicating the leader, ready to automagically accept leader status should the current leader fail. The replication factor MUST be smaller than the number of brokers on your cluster when creating a topic.

From the introduction:

> > [For a topic with replication factor N, we will tolerate up to N-1 server failures without losing any messages committed to the log.](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_guarantees)

You could get many replicas on one machine by running multiple brokers on it (maybe on different disks or something, for whatever reason).

**Question 3**

> Difference between a {High level, Low level} + {Producer, Consumer}

There is really only one Producer API (There exists a legacy Scala client). There are three Consumer APIs. The old High and Low level APIs and the new unified API. You will most likely want to use the new unified API if you are running Kafka 0.9.0 or newer (which you will likely be, if you are getting started). It includes new features not available to the old Consumer APIs (e.g. security features introduced in 0.9.0), and there should be no need for the old ones (unless your chosen library does not support the new API, which most likely would mean you should switch).

[no-kafka](https://github.com/oleksiyk/kafka) supports a [SimpleConsumer API](https://github.com/oleksiyk/kafka#simpleconsumer), which iirc models the old low level API. It can be good for simple testing, but I strongly recommend the [GroupConsumer API, which uses the new unified API](https://github.com/oleksiyk/kafka#groupconsumer-new-unified-consumer-api). One of its strengths (committing offsets), is discussed in relation to the next question.

**Question 4**

> If Kafka doesn't store the consumer position, what are the best methods of storing it? Do people use databases or they may store it as local information to the client.

You could really store them anyway you want (on disk etc.). The new unified Consumer API saves your consumer's offset (which message it has been sent) automagically. Your consumer should also commit its latest processed offset after successfully processing a message ([consumer.commitOffset in no-kafka GroupConsumer](https://github.com/oleksiyk/kafka#groupconsumer-new-unified-consumer-api)), so if you reconnect the consumer after a reboot or whatever, you will get the newest message you yourself have marked as not successfully consumed.

This is one of many excellent reasons for using the new unified Consumer API as well.

The offsets are stored in a highly available (replicated), partitioned topic and cached by Kafka. [You can also configure the options for offset saving (search for options with offset. or offsets. behind this link.](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs)

One used to commit a consumers offset to ZooKeeper, a service which Kafka relies on for distributed services, such as configuration, but ZooKeeper doesn't scale well for many writes and has been abstracted away from Kafka's API. This is how [SimpleConsumer in no-kafka](https://github.com/oleksiyk/kafka#simpleconsumer) saves its offsets as well.

**Question 5**

> Is is a good idea to build a pub-sub system with Kafka and Node.js (to provide rest API for the data)?

There is nothing wrong with doing that. I myself have made some demos with Node.js + Kafka recently, and thoroughly enjoy it. As stated above I recommend the [no-kafka](https://github.com/oleksiyk/kafka) library for Kafka >0.9, but the older (for >0.8) [kafka-node](https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node) works as well, since 0.9 is backwards-compatible. Even if because of nothining else, I would choose no-kafka for its support of the unified Consumer API.

In addition to making a client-facing interface with Node.js, you can also easily accomplish light stream processing (e.g. enriching and reformatting gathered events) with it. Maybe formatting the Kafka logs to a database for example.

Heavy stream processing may not be best accomplished with Node.js, as implementing resource management, fault-tolerance and such would be a big undertaking, and there are good stream processing frameworks (Samza, Spark etc.) for such tasks. Yes, they are in different languages, but you will probably find a framework suitable for you. You could probably even prototype heavy tasks with Node.js, if you are familiar with developing and deploying performant, optimised Node applications.